# server: Name or service not known BIND9

Tags: linux, server, dns, ubuntu-20.04, bind9

[image]

[image]

[image]

root@server: ping -c 4 servidor
ping: servidor: Name or service not known

Could someone please tell me if I have any syntax errors or is it some other kind of error? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `db.domain.com` file should be as follows, You also forgot the NS records

```
    $ORIGIN .
$TTL 604800     ; 1 week
domain.com           IN SOA  f95. root.domain.com. (
                                165       ; serial
                                604800     ; refresh (1 week)
                                86400      ; retry (1 day)
                                2419200    ; expire (4 weeks)
                                604800     ; minimum (1 week)
                                )
                        NS      ns1.domain.com.
                        NS      ns2.domain.com.
                        AAAA    ::1
                        MX      10 mail.domain.com.
```

after any change to this file you should change serial number and then restart bind service.